# dpkg error code 1

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line-interface, ubuntu-9.10, dpkg

I am unable to add/remove any packages in ubuntu karmic

I keep getting the following

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
crossplatfromui
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What do I do to completely remove this package ?

Comment: Do something like `dpkg -D776 -r crossplatfromui` and post the output.

Comment: Is that the only output it gives, feel free to include all the output that you get.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/crossplatfromui.{pre,post}rm
dpkg -r crossplatfromui
```

Answer (score 0):

dpkg --purge thePackage

That also removes configuration files.. just use --remove if you want to keep them.

However, I still have the same problem. It keeps on coming back when i try to install a package i need. Perhaps i've fudged my system.. ;)

Where can i find a list of what the error codes mean?

Answer (score 0):

To figure out what an error code means do this:

bash $ perror 1

but normally you get the error exact same error and code when you are debugging anyways!

Comment: The exit code of an application is not the same as an errno. So this wouldn't do anything useful in this case.